# How to use many one to one morph relation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a user model that has several files that have a one-to-one morph relationship with them :

```
User                                               File
_______________________                           _________________________
id                                                 id
name                                               url
email                                              ...
...                                                filable_type
loa_file_id                                        filable_id
passport_file_id
```

How can I establish the relationship between loa_file_id and file and also the relationship between passport_file_id and file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `File` Model:

```php
class File extends Model
{
    public function fileable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('filable');
    }
}
```

And in `User` Model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function loaFile()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(File::class, 'filable', 'filable_type', 'loa_file_id');
    }

    public function passportFile()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(File::class, 'filable', 'filable_type', 'passport_file_id');
    }
}
```

With these relationships defined, you can now access the associated file for a user as follows:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$loaFile = $user->loaFile;
$passportFile = $user->passportFile;
```